# Execute Raw SQL on Entity Framework Migration

Tags: entity-framework

I need to execute raw SQL as part of my database initialization with Entity Framework. The SQL is required to set the collation of a column and when given a context the code looks something like this

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column nvarchar(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS");
```

The question is where to put this code? If I put it in the `Seed` method of `Configuration.cs` created by EF when I `enable-migrations` it'll work but I'll lose all knowledge of performing the SQL if I decide to delete the migrations and rebaseline at a later date. Ideally I want to abstract this SQL execution to another class that EF knows to execute each time I enable migrations and update the database.

I thought about using a [database initializer](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) but on further reading it appears that these are only invoked by the calling application: this shouldn't be the responsibility of the calling application - I want it to set the collation when entity framework creates the database.

How can I ensure that I execute raw SQL as part of my EF initial/baseline configuration such that I won't lose knowledge of what was done in the future (i.e. not just lumping it all into the seed method of the default `Configuration.cs`)

Answer (score 4):

```
void Up() {
   Sql("ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column nvarchar(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS");
}
```

Another option is to do that as part of Seed method, but migrations seems more sane.

Comment: Sure, but is embedding this a migration the only way? When building the database for the first time I often find myself clearing out the migrations and starting fresh otherwise I end up with a load of migrations that are really just noise as the model develops. I'd have to remember to add these sql statement each time.

Comment: Did you find another solution for this yet, @JamesB?